# flutter google tag manager android not sending any data in GA

Tags: android, flutter, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have installed firebase SDK and the events are going into firebase debugview
[image]

created a tag with all events on GTM going back to a customer image and to a GA property 
[image]

Submit , download the json file and put it inside 
android/app/src/main/assets/containers

Followed the documentation of firebase + GTM to put the GTM dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Work around for googletagmanager-gradle-plugin compatibility
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

But my problem now is that the events are not going to GA nor to my image. 
I am wondering if there is a way to debug to know why the events are not send.

I have activated the VERBOSE of google tag manager but i am not able to find any line that throws an error

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GoogleTagManager VERBOSE
```

If you guys have an idea of what is going on , maybe I am not putting the json in the proper folder

Comment: Hi, Were you able to find the solution?